# Convert MySQL times tamp column from one timezone to another

Tags: mysql

Need some ideas on how to convert an entire database TIMESTAMP columns from one timezone to another.

The current server is UTC, MySQL is also UTC so everything is good in that area.  All time related columns are TIMESTAMPs.  The problem is that when the time information was being entered, they were in EST/EDT.  For example, enter start time: data is 1/1/2011 08:00:00 AM (EST/EDT).  Because timezone wasn't implemented at the start, the database stored this as 08:00:00 UTC.  So all the data in the database is stored like this.  Once we get data that requires timezone info, this model will break.

The question is: how do you convert all these TIMESTAMP columns into the correct UTC time?  The code will be changed to deal with this on the display side on a go-forward basis but what about historic data?

The simplest way seems to do a mysqldump --tz-utc of some sort and then import the data back, then release the code.  However, I can't seem to find a good example of how to do this properly or if there are other ways to do this in the most efficient way possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Could you use the MySQL [AddTime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) function to update the existing data?

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyTimeColumn = ADDTIME (MyTimeColumn, -8:00:00) WHERE <the data is bad>
```

Comment: This would not take summertime in to account.